# Djangoで複数のテーブルを結合して取得したい

Tags: python, django

複数のテーブルを結合した結果を取得したいです。
メインとなるテーブルからは直接紐づかない形になります。
言葉では説明が難しいので以下に例を記載します。

良い例が浮かばず不自然なテーブル構成になっていますがご了承ください。

#### モデル定義

```py
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user_name = models.CharField()

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_group'

    comment = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group'

    group_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    group_name = models.CharField()
```

#### テーブルのデータ

```
## User
user_id, user_name
1, taro
2, hanako

## Group
group_id, group_name
1, group1
2, group2

## UserGroup
id, comment, user_id, group_id
1, comment_x, 1, 1
2, comment_y, 1, 2
```

#### 取得したい形

イメージですので、細部が異なっていても問題ありません

```py
users = User.objects..... # 質問したい所

users[0].group[0].name # group1
users[0].user_group[0].comment # comment_x
users[0].user_group[0].group.group_name # group1
```

#### JSON的なイメージ

```js
{
  user_id: 1,
  user_name: taro,
  group:[
    {
      group_id: 1,
      group_name: group1
    },
    {
      group_id: 2,
      group_name: group2
    }
  ],
  user_group:[
    {
      comment: comment_x,
      group: {
          group_id: 1,
          group_name: group1
      }
    },
    {
      comment: comment_y,
      group: {
          group_id: 2,
          group_name: group2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### SQLで取得する場合

構造化されないので厳密には異なりますが。。。

```sql
select * from user
inner join user_group on user.user_id = user_group.user_id
inner join group on group.group_id = user_group.group_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToManyFieldで2つモデム(User,Group)のみでいいと思います。

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    user_name = models.CharField()
```